# Qt resize event for docks

Tags: qt, resize, signals, dock, qdockwidget

Is there a way to catch resize events for docks in Qt? I need to be able to detect when a dock is resized (and not only when its location or 'features' change). It looks like there is no 'resized' signal for QDockWidget.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not wish to subclass to just get resize event control, you can [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)

Small example would look like (`MainWindow.h`): (MainWindow holds DockWidget Here)

```
protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
```

and in (`MainWindow.cc`):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {
  ui_.setupUi(this);
  ui_.dockWidget->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize && obj == ui_.dockWidget) {
      QResizeEvent *resizeEvent = static_cast<QResizeEvent*>(event);
      qDebug("Dock Resized (New Size) - Width: %d Height: %d",
             resizeEvent->size().width(),
             resizeEvent->size().height());
  } 
  return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: If I wish to subclass, should overriding `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event) override;` do the trick?